# Issues Making GET Request in Node JS

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, http-post, http-get

I'm building a backend for an Android app which uses nodejs on the server side,the android app makes a POST request with the required parameters to the server,the server is suppossed to do the processing and send the response to the requested user as SMS.I have a transactional SMS gateway API which is working perfectly to send SMS as GET request from the browser.but the same API doesnt send SMS while making a GET request to the API in the node script using the request module...

Given below is my code,Please suggest where am i going wrong..

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var userName = "myUserName";
var passWord = "myPassWord";
var senderID = "mySenderID";
var content;
var from_number;

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
response.send('We Dont Reply for GET/,make a POST/ instead..');
});

app.post('/',
bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
function(req, res) {
    content = req.body.content; //Parameters passed as POST Request from my Android App
    from_number = req.body.from_number;
    console.log('making request to offlinebrowser-web with URL as ' +  content + ' and sender as ' + from_number );
    request("http://offlinebrowser-web.appspot.com/ExtractServlet?url=http://"+content+"&OutputType=1&ExtractorType=1", function(error, response, data) {
    console.log('backend response : ' + data); //logs to console the  valid output of GET Request
    console.log('initiating response module'); 
    request("**3.*5.*4.1*9/api/v3/sendsms/plain?user="+userName+"&password="+passWord+"sZd5y6AA&sender="+senderID+"&SMSText="+data+"&type=longsms&GSM="+from_number, function(error, response, body)
    //making a GET request to the above link in browser,perfectly sends an SMS,but here doesnt work!
    {
        console.log(body); //this line logs undefined to the console
    });
    res.status(200).end();
    });
});
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
 });
```

Comment: Did you console.log the error or status code? If so, what are they?

Comment: console.log(body) for the API request logs 'undefined' as i mentioned in the comment in the code

Comment: Sure, but what about error or status-code?

Comment: but the same URI for which node gives me invalid URI error works fine and sms gets sent while testing on a browser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have solved this problem by just prefixing the API URI with an http://